# Send key combination from C using X11 (GTK, GDK) functions

Tags: c, gtk, x11, gdk, xdotool

I need exact equivalent of command (in C code)

```
system("xdotool key alt+o");
```

but much more portable (and less overloaded for so simple task).
I write for GTK so i prefer some GTK function, but something for GDK or even for X11 also looks to be portable.
Thanks.

Comment: Look at the xtest extension